# how to add arcgis 10.1 rest service in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I need to add ArcGis 10.1 rest services to openlayers. Can any one share the ideas, it would be great.

Comment: Ok, even then my service is not working:new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest( "ArcGIS Server Layer", "http://geoportal.abudhabi.ae/rest/services/BaseMapSatellite1M/MapServer", {layers: "show:0,2"});.  i am struggling with a lot.  i am using ArcGIS 10.1.  Any help would be great..

Comment: I found the solution, which is not duplicate posted.  We have to use openlayers 2.13.1 and use arcgiscache method. it will solve maximum issues related to integrating arcgis 10.1 mapservices to openlayers...